# How to override jquery.validate in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm using magento 2.1. version.

I have tried to override file `lib/web/jquery/jquery.validate.js` and still I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Comment: I'm tried like this but it doesn't work

Comment: attach what u try and why it's does'not work

Comment: I'm doing  as the example in guide

Answer (score 1):

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery/jquery.validate':'js/jquery.validate',
        }
    },
};
```

I put this code in requirejs-config.js in theme.
Next I create jquery.validate in web/js.